# SimpleXML error 'Call to a member function on a non-object'

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I keep getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in /www/zzl.org/t/h/e/theseminary/htdocs/submit.php on line 3

My code, in its own php file, is as follows:

```
<?php
$xmlobject = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$xmlobject[0]->channel[0]->posts[0]->addChild("item");
$itemcount = $xmlobject->channel->posts->count();
$xmlobject->channel[0]->posts[0]->item[$itemcount]->addChild("title", $title);
$xmlobject->channel->posts->item[$itemcount]->addChild("content", $content);
$xmlobject->asxml("data.xml");
header( "Location: $url" );
?>
```

I realize this question has been asked multiple times, but I could not find a solution to *my* problem.

Here's the XML file, if it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<channel>
<title></title>
<description></description>
<posts>
</posts>
</channel>
```

Comment: show your xml-file, please

Comment: @michi Done! It's a file I generated with SimpleXML, by converting a string into XML.

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 3):

Change this...

```
$xmlobject[0]->channel[0]->posts[0]->addChild("item");
```

to this...

```
$xmlobject->posts[0]->addChild("item");
```

Reason: `<channel>` is your root-element, and `$xmlobject` represents the root-element.

This is why it is essential to post the XML as well.
see live demo @ http://codepad.viper-7.com/DffgLG

BTW, this line...

```
$itemcount = $xmlobject->posts->count();
```

will count `<posts>`-nodes, if you want to count `<item>s`, go...

```
$itemcount = $xmlobject->posts->item->count();
```

... and remember to do `$itemcount--` because indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Error is referred to this line

```
$xmlobject[0]->channel[0]->posts[0]->addChild("item");
```

and is "speaking" to you exactly what's going on.

Simply `posts[0]` isn't an object (is like you're trying to do something like `1->addChild("item");` or `'foo'->addChild("item");` or `null->addChild("item");`)

Are you sure that `->post[0]` will return a value (so, a `SimpleXMLElement` object) ?

Comment: I changed the code so that at every level of the file (`$xmlobject`, `channel`, `posts`, etc.) it attempts to add a child. It did not give an error for the main level (so `$xmlobject->addChild("item")` worked, but not the rest). Maybe I'll try ditching the channel tag. It's unnecessary anyway.

Comment: I removed the channel tag, but received the same error. Is my syntax wrong or something? I know for a fact that the file "data.xml" exists and is a properly formatted xml file, and it seems to be working at the top level.

Comment: @user1313992: please, update your answer with xml file so we could guess what is going on there